# interpretation of the JSON Patch spec

Tags: json, patch

I have a question about the interpretation of JSON Patch ([RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)).

Suppose I had a resource that looked like this:

```
{
   "type": "assembly",
   "uri": "http://example.com/campSrv/Assembly/18",
   "name": "/sample",
   "description": "Hello, World Application",
   "created": "2013-03-27T16:15Z",
   ...
}
```

The definition of this resource says that it could have a value called "tags" which is defined as being an array of strings. However, this resource currently has no tags, so my service doesn't serialize the non-existent array.

Now suppose I submit the following HTTP PATCH request:

```
PATCH http://example.com/campSrv/Assembly/18 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch

[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/tags/0", "value": "flobbit" }
]
```

Should this create the 'tags' array and add 'flobbit' as the first/only element or should my server return an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding ...

Your patch will result in an error because `tags` does not exist, and you can't add to an array that does not yet exist.

> [RFC 6902 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.1)
>
> ...
>
> However, the object itself or an array containing it does need to
> exist, and it remains an error for that not to be the case.  For
> example, an "add" with a target location of "/a/b" starting with this
> document:
>
> { "a": { "foo": 1 } }
>
> is not an error, because "a" exists, and "b" will be added to its
> value.  It is an error in this document:
>
> { "q": { "bar": 2 } }
>
> because "a" does not exist.

This patch, however, will add a `tags` string with a value of `"flobbit"`.

```
[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/tags", "value": "flobbit" }
]
```

And this patch will add `tags` array with the first element being `"fobbit"`.

```
[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/tags", "value": ["flobbit"] }
]
```

Comment: `{ "op": "add", "path": "/tags", "value": ["flobbit"] }` In above case, what about if tags array already exists, should one add "flobbit" to it or replace the entire array with the contents of supplied array?
(Versus using op "replace" which should reject request if tags array does not exist).
(If feels most natural to replace the entire array, so if wanting to add multiple values you use multiple operations)

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. But, I'd interpret that to mean, "add an array containing a single element `'flobbit'` to the existing array." So, the updated `tags` property will look something like, `["existing value", "existing value2", "etc.", ["flobbit"]]`.

Comment: @svidgen I believe this to be incorrect. RFC6902 specifies this for the 'add' operation: "If the target location specifies an object member that does exist, that member's value is replaced." - it then goes on to show how to add something to an existing array: "An element to add to an existing array [...] If the "-" character is used to index the end of the array (see [RFC6901]), this has the effect of  appending the value to the array" 
So the patch should look like { "op": "add", "path": "/tags/-", "value": "flobbit" } if you want to add the element "flobbit" to the existing array.