# HTTP PATCH: Handling arrays, deletion, and nested key creation

Tags: json, api, http, rest, architecture

I'm looking for a practical guide to implementing the `PATCH` verb for partial updates of a noun in a RESTful api using JSON. Understanding that `PATCH` is for partial updates, we lack still standardization around the syntax for deleting keys, creating or updating nested keys, and arrays.

Let's say I `GET` an object:

```
// GET users/42
{
  id: 42,
  name: 'SimpleAsCouldBe',
  city: 'San Francisco',
  roles: ['viewer','editor'],
  posts: {
    '01': {},
    '02': {},
  }
}
```

...Then I want to update it:

```
// PATCH users/42
{
  name: 'SimpleGuy',                   // CLEAR:   update the key's value
  email: 'hey@google.com',             // CLEAR:   add the new key
  city: null                           // UNCLEAR: delete the key?
  roles: ['owner'],                    // UNCLEAR: replace the whole array?
  posts: {
    '02': { title:'how to pop lock' }, // CLEAR:  update nested key
    '03': { title:'how to salsa' }     // CLEAR:  create new nested key
  }
  notes: {
    '01': { title: 'a note title' }    // CLEAR (but disallowed?): create wrapping key
  }
}
```

The PATCH rfc says [no to creating nested keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930516/interpretation-of-the-json-patch-spec). This is a spec bug, I think, because creating a nested key is non-ambiguous.

I could send a full object diff, like [this library](https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch) generates, but this makes the clear case of adding or updating a key more verbose.

How do I handle arrays, deletion, and nested keys in a lean way with HTTP PATCH?

Comment: You should be using [JSON Pointers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901) to refer to nested elements in the target document structure.  [JSON Patch](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) uses an ordered sequence of operations to update the target JSON object.  Arrays are valid values for an operation described in a JSON Patch document.

Comment: This is a really useful link, @countfloortiles, thank you. We'd been wondering how to represent paths to tree data and it's nice to have a spec to work against.

Answer (score 32):

The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) clearly details how to format the JSON body of a PATCH request. You're using a totally different format. Given that, I'm not surprised at all that there is ambiguity. The body should look something like:

```
   [
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "SimpleGuy" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/email", "value": "hey@google.com" },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/city", "value": null },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/roles", "value": [ "owner" ] },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/posts/02/title", "value": "how to pop lock" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/posts/", "value": "03" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/posts/03/title", "value": "how to salsa" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/notes", "value": { "title": "a note title" } }
   ]
```

Go back and read the spec. It even gives examples which address most of your questions.

Comment: thanks, just curious in what case it will create a new resource? all of them are op add?

Comment: @AlanLee Yes, I would expect that adds would create a new resource. Replaces, deletes would not.

Comment: Thanks, I am implementing the PATCH request and need to determiner whether create or update the existing record.

Comment: [rfc7396 JSON Merge Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396) provides a spec that is consistent w/ the proposed request in the original question.

Comment: @JamesConkling That RFC came out in October 2014, 6 months after my answer. :)

Comment: If my `/posts` resource is an array of `Post` objects, does it make sense to do something like `{ "op": "add", "path": "/posts/-", "value": "03" }` Where `03` is some unique id of an existing post? Is the server supposed to realize the value is an id and not a `Post` object, and know how to lookup the actual `Post` to add that object to the resource? It seems odd to me that this would be expected.

Comment: @crush - that is an array index, it will not look into your object for identifying information

Comment: @JamesConkling The RFC7396 does not have appropriate array handling, so imo it should be avoided in any system that uses arrays.