# Trying to patch array on rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

I cannot successfully push a value to an array that is part of a object on a rest api. I am following this [Patching arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820318/http-patch-handling-arrays-deletion-and-nested-key-creation) but I cannot get it to work.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

const formData = { "op": "add", "path": "/residents", "value": this.state.person.id };
console.log(formData)

xhr.open('PATCH', 'http://localhost:3008/planets/' + this.state.person.planetID);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.addEventListener('load', () => { 

    //patch the person const planet id 

});
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Does your backend understands JSON Patch and if yes, what is the error message you're getting in return?

Comment: yes it does. Here is what i get instead of pushing to the array and no error:   {
    "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.421Z",
    "climate": "temperate, tropical",
    "surface_water": "8",
    "name": "Yavin IV",
    "diameter": "10200",
    "rotation_period": "24",
    "created": "2014-12-10T11:37:19.144Z",
    "terrain": "jungle, rainforests",
    "gravity": "1 standard",
    "orbital_period": "4818",
    "population": "1000",
    "id": 3,
    "residents": [],
    "films": [
      1
    ],
    "[object Object]": ""
  },

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [RFC Doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.16) for json patch, you need to append an '-' to the path:

```
const formData = { "op": "add", "path": "/residents/-", "value": this.state.person.id };
```

or specify an explicit index, where you want to add the value into the array.

Comment: wont push to the array . {
  "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.423Z",
  "climate": "frozen",
  "surface_water": "100",
  "name": "Hoth",
  "diameter": "7200",
  "rotation_period": "23",
  "created": "2014-12-10T11:39:13.934Z",
  "terrain": "tundra, ice caves, mountain ranges",
  "gravity": "1.1 standard",
  "orbital_period": "549",
  "population": "unknown",
  "id": 4,
  "residents": [],
  "films": [
    2
  ],
  "[object Object]": ""
}